# How are these two sentences equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How are these two sentences equivalent?

1. Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial such that it is the multiplication of two polynomials with rational coefficients. Then $f(x)$ is also the multiplication of two polynomials with integer coefficients.
2. If $f(x)$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well, the second statement in completely trivial as $\;\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb Q\;$ . Perhaps you want the *other* direction, with the added condition that $\;f\;$ is an integer polynomial...?

Comment: This statement is known as Gauss's Lemma, you can find your answers by starting here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: The first statement is also trivial because $f=f\cdot 1$.

Comment: I don't want proof to neither. I just want to know *how* statements 1 and 2 are equivalent?

Comment: The polynomial $2x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. You need some more hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

Both are true statements, so they are equivalent.

In general let $D$ be an integral domain, then $f\in D[x]$ is irreducible iff $f\in F[x]$ is irreducible where $F$ is the field of quotient of $D$. This can be proved using Gauss Lemma.